# showing monotone convergence holds when f_1 is integrable and fn are necessarily not nonnegative

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Prove that the monotone convergence theorem still holds if the assumption that the functions $f_1, f_2, ... $ are non-negative is dropped, and the assumption that $f_1$ is integrable is added.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Problem is, am i supposed to do without using monotone convergence theorem and do from scratch or use the theorem in some way, in another question, where functions are decreasing and f_1 is integrable, we can consider f_1-f_n and apply monotone convergence theorem, but I couldn't do same thing in this question.

Comment: Why not? ..…………

Comment: Oh, I think we need to consider,fn-f_1 as sequence of function and since it is increasing and non-negative, we are done.

Comment: @noidea that’s almost right, but the ‘we are done’ is subtle. Why is integrability of $f_1$ a necessary hypothesis?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I think it is necessary because we get integral of f-f1 at the end and to cancel f_1 on both sides and to make expression sense and avoid ( infinity-infinity ) case, we need integral to exist. i.e . finite.

Comment: That's exactly right. For a counterexample without integrability of $f_1$, consider the real line as your measure space and the simple functions $f_n:=-\chi_{[n,\infty)}$